# Log4j2 AsyncAppender performance test

Tags: java, logging, performance-testing, log4j2, jmh

I am writing a JMH benchmark to test the performance of logback's AsyncAppender.

As a starting point, I looked at log4j2's performance tests but looks like they are not end to end measurements. For example, the test here [Log4j2 Async Appender Benchmark](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-perf/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/perf/jmh/AsyncAppenderLog4j2Benchmark.java) is only testing the throughput of wrapping the loggable data in an object and en-queuing it into the disruptor (the backing queue).

```
@Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void throughput2Params() {
        logger.info("p1={}, p2={}", one, two);
    }
```

Is this all or have I missed a test where the throughout measurement is from calling logger.info() to the background thread writing the data to disk/console/db etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using JMH for benchmarking end-to-end async logging (with a real appender like FileAppender) is that JMH produces many log events very fast. The FileAppender cannot keep up so the (fixed size) async queue fills up immediately.

Once the queue is full, logging performance slows down to something worse than plain synchronous file logging.

We found we needed to be very clear about what we wanted to measure, and we ended up separately measuring how fast events can be enqueued while there's space, and how fast the FileAppender can write events to disk.

With JMH it's difficult to measure both at the same time in an end-to-end test because JMH won't let you control how many events you fire off (as far as I know). So it's hard to avoid filling up the queue. I suspect that you're not that interested in how fast async logging is after the queue is full, since this is extremely rare.

The approach we took for the [Log4j2 performance tests](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html) is to use JMH with a no-op appender for async logging tests, and have separate JMH benchmarks for synchronous file logging.

For the original [Async Logger performance tests](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance) we wrote a custom performance testing framework that tested in bursts of no more events than the queue size. (The PerfTest, MTPerfTest and PerfTestDriver classes which can be found in the Log4j 2 unit test source directory.) This was not easy to get right either: you need to ensure the test does proper warm up, ensure that all logging threads start at the same time, run the benchmark in a separate JVM from the test driver and collect the results somehow, etc.

P.S.

Be aware that ConsoleAppender is roughly 50x slower (!) than logging to a file. Using console logging to compare performance of logging libraries is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi Remko, thanks for your response. I agree that measuring Async logger using JMH is not easy. Perhaps because JMH is for micro and not end to end benchmarking. I also see your reasoning about splitting the test cases. I avoided writing my own test harness because I knew I wouldn't know how to correct issues like "co-ordinated omissions" etc. I am now looking at JLBH. It builds upon JMH but is designed to measure things in context and not isolation. Still playing around with it but looks like you can control iteration count with it. Will share my test case once I have it working. Cheers!

Comment: Understood. Be sure to test multithreaded scenarios. This is more difficult but often overlooked. Size the queue so that it can hold the total number of events, not just for a single thread.

Comment: One more thing: coordinated omission will rear its head in latency tests but with throughput tests you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Much appreciated Remko! I also found your chat with the heavyweights on Mechanical Sympathy google forum. This measurement business ain't easy for sure :) Cheers and congrats on the success of log4j2.